# Gmail is automatically labeling messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have my university email account set up in Gmail to send and receive. Previously, I created a filter that would move all messages to foo@bar.edu to the foo@bar.edu label. I have since deleted that filter and changed the name of the label foo@bar.edu to Bar, but messages that are sent to foo@bar.edu are still being labeled as Bar. What is causing this?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you haven't told Gmail to automatically add a label on POP3 import:

To check go to:

1. Settings
2. Accounts and Import
3. Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)
4. Edit

Make sure the "Label incoming messages" checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Kevin: If this answer gave you the answer you needed, please consider "Accepting" it in order to act as a signpost for future readers. For more information see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)